# How to iterate over the next element in a tuple in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Say I have a tuple :

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
```

Now I want to do something like :

```
for i in a:
    if i == 1:
        print a[1]
```

I mean if the first element is 1 I want to immediately extract the second element without going into another iteration of the for loop.

How may I do this in a django template?

Comment: Is there a reason that `if a[0]==1: print a[1]` does not work?

Comment: why would you want to do something like this ?

Comment: @drewk I want do it in a django template. Its just that I dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does effectively the same thing as your Python code, assuming that you've passed `a` to the template context:

```
{% for i in a %}

    {% if i == 1 %}

        {{ a.1 }}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for i in a %}{% ifequal i 1 %}{{ a.1 }}{% endifequal %}{% endfor %}
```